# Is this a safe way to use java to encrypt (using public private key) messages that might be sent across insecure networks

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I am not an expert on this so I need to defer to an expert. Is the following example a reasonably secure way to encrypt and decrypt a message (of an unknown length) for transmission a potentially insecure network (i.e. Email, HTTP requests, or other means). By "reasonably secure" I mean, would prevent a casual, or semi determined third party from reading the message.

Encrypt a message with a random AES key, and protect AES key by encrypting it with a public key.

```
public static String encrypt(String data, PublicKey publicKey) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {

    // Create AES secret key
    Cipher aes = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    kgen.init(256);
    SecretKey key = kgen.generateKey();
    SecretKeySpec aeskeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getEncoded(), "AES");

    // Encrypt data with AES Secret key
    aes.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aeskeySpec);
    byte[] dataEncoded = aes.doFinal(data.getBytes());

    // Encrypt the secret AES key with the public key
    Cipher rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    rsa.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    byte[] aesKeyEncoded = rsa.doFinal(key.getEncoded());

    // Output both secret AES key and data
    return
        Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(aesKeyEncoded) + "~" +
        Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(dataEncoded);

}
```

Decrypt the AES secret key, and then decrypt the message:

```
public static String decrypt(String data, PrivateKey privateKey) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
    String[] parts = data.split("~");

    // Decrypt AES secret key
    byte[] encodedSecretKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(parts[0]);
    Cipher rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    rsa.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    byte[] decodedSecretKey = rsa.doFinal(encodedSecretKey);
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(decodedSecretKey, "AES");

    // Decrypt message
    Cipher aes = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    aes.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decodedData = aes.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(parts[1]));

    return new String(decodedData);
}
```

Using the above methods:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeyException {
    // Generate public/private key
    KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    generator.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom());
    KeyPair kp = generator.generateKeyPair();

    System.out.println(" Public key = " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(kp.getPublic().getEncoded()));
    System.out.println("Private key = " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(kp.getPrivate().getEncoded()));

    String mytext = "test message with some test data.";

    String e = encrypt(mytext, kp.getPublic());
    String d = decrypt(e, kp.getPrivate());

    System.out.println("        text = " + mytext);
    System.out.println("Decoded text = " + d);

}
```

Comment: This doesn't look right, AES is not a public/private key cryptosystem. Does it work?

Comment: Assuming you cannot use TLS (which basically does the same thing) it is OK. But keep in mind that the security depends on many factors. For example, are you sure to really have the public key of the intended recipient?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, it's common to use a symmetric cipher with a random "session key" for encrypting most of the data, and then encrypt just the session key using a public-key cipher.  The reason is that symmetric ciphers are generally faster than asymmetric ones.

Comment: @Wyzard Yes. But without padding or encoding? I didn't declare it wrong, because I was aware of the symmetric component.

Comment: The mechanism you describe is reasonably secure against casual attacks, provided the private key is never transmitted. It's a slightly simplified version of what SSL uses, in fact.  I do agree with others that using actual SSL would be better where you can, though it wouldn't work for email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you can trust the RSA public key the general idea is OK. If you just send the public key to the other side, then it is not.

You also need to protect your ciphertext by adding integrity and authenticity. You can easily do this by switching to AES / GCM mode (which is only available in Java 8, or using Bouncy Castle). Currently you are using the unsafe AES / ECB mode of encryption.

You should try and use RSA with OAEP padding, instead of PKCS#1 v1.5 padding. In general, you should not rely on default character encodings (`getBytes()`) or cipher modes.

So in the end: no, that's not secure. Try and use TLS is you want to avoid the many pitfalls.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I would use TLS if I could, I need the next best thing